# If someone set the login redirect URL to a wrong URL in Cognos , how to fix it?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

If  someone  set  the  login redirect  URL  to a wrong URL  in  Cognos , how to fix it?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v84S.jpg

Comment: Are you able to access the product at all right now via the gateway or dispatcher URI?

Comment: Yes ,I am a administrator

Comment: Login will be redirect to a wrong URI so I can’t fix it from origin UI

Comment: No one knows the correct answer in this site ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an uploaded extension or view contains errors, it can render IBM® Cognos® Analytics unusable. In this case, you can run Cognos Analytics with customized extensions and views disabled.
Procedure
Start Cognos Analytics by typing the URL <webserver_name>:<port_number>/bi/?factoryMode=true.
Results

Cognos Analytics starts with all extensions disabled. You can now correct or delete your customized extensions or views before you restart Cognos Analytics with the standard URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think the file you are looking for is the Default.html file in:

D:\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\webcontent

You can aslo create your own Login html file like the following example:
[Cognos login URL](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-redirect-users-after-log-cognos-analytics-111)

Best regards,
Rubrix

Comment: I try it  But nothing changed. thanks Rubrix.  The  login redirect URL has a higher priority.

Comment: Even though the login redirect URL is empty ,the origin login page has a higher priority than Default.html. so change Default.html is useless https://imgur.com/a/PHl3TRz

Comment: what should I  check  in   C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost  ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your applicationHost file at: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config